# I am trying to assign the specific value base on condition in pandas: gives me SettingWithCopyWarning error

Tags: python, pandas

My data frame is dff, and it has columns named 'amount'.I am using the following comands:

```
dff.amount[(dff['amount']<5)]=0
```

it gives the following error:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

What is the reason?

Comment: Use `dff.loc[(dff['amount']<5), 'amount']=0`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
dff.amount = np.where(dff['amount']<5, 0, dff.amount)
```